# Multiple IFS in Sharepoiint Calculated columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I am trying to write a formula in a calculated column that would populate shift hours base on shift name.
The Shift title column is names "ERSShift".

The different shifts available are "Night Shift","Night Shift Weekend/Holiday","Day Shift","Day Shift Weekend/Holiday", "Supervisor Coverage" and "Day Shift".

The Shift "Night Shift" when entered should auto populate "3pm-7am" in my calculated column
The Shift "Night Shift Weekend/Holiday" should auto populate "7pm-7am" in my calculated column
The Shift "Day Shift Weekend/Holiday" should auto populate "7am-7pm"
The remaining 2 shifts have no shift hours associated and can be left blank.

I came up with this formula but it is broke, can you tell me what I am missing?

```
=IF(ERSShift="Day Shift Weekend/Holiday","7am-7pm",IF(ERSShift="Night Shift","3pm-7am",IF(ERSShift="Night Shift Weekend/Holiday","7pm-7am",""))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF([ERSShift]="Day Shift Weekend/Holiday","7am-7pm",IF([ERSShift]="Night Shift","3pm-7am",IF([ERSShift]="Night Shift Weekend/Holiday","7pm-7am","")))
```

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. The choice column values you are using in formula are case sensitive. So make sure you are using the choices exactly as mentioned in column setting.

**Official Documentations**:

1. [Calculated Field Formulas](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)).
2. [IF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a).

Comment: Hi @Lisa, have you tried this formula? does this work for you?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your formula, but you have typed an extra "**)**" at the end.

I've tested with your original formula, removed the last "**)**" and it works fine.